nextjs layout hydration error hydration failed
I have my main page at /, and I want it to have a different layout than the rest of my app.
The problem is, I have some CSS that applies to the HTML element itself. I tried adding it to the div wrapping page.tsx or applying it to main/body, but for some reason, it’s not working.
Here’s my root layout at src/app:
import { Rubik } from 'next/font/google';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import Providers from './Providers';
import { Toaster } from 'sonner';
import './globals.css';

const rubik = Rubik({
  weight: '500',
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html className={`${rubik.className} bg-[#f3f4f6]`} lang="he-IL" dir="rtl">
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      <Providers>
        <body>
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Toaster richColors closeButton />
        </body>
      </Providers>
    </html>
  );
}

And here’s the layout for the / route (the main page) at src/app/(root)/layout.tsx (alongside page.tsx in the same route folder):
import { Rubik } from 'next/font/google';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import '../globals.css';
import { Toaster } from '@/components/ui/sonner';
import Providers from '../Providers';

const rubik = Rubik({
  weight: '500',
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

export default async function HomeLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html
      className={`${rubik.className} bg-background2 text-[66.6%]`}
      lang="he-IL"
      dir="rtl"
    >
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      <Providers>
        <body>
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Toaster richColors closeButton />
        </body>
      </Providers>
    </html>
  );
}

I'm encountering a hydration error, and the UI doesn’t render properly. The issue is that it initializes with the RootLayout, but then the HTML element changes, which causes the font-size to switch to 66.6%, triggering a rerender and messing up the layout.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

You should have only one root layout. Or one per segment. But never one in the root and one in the segment.
From the docs:

Creating multiple root layouts
To create multiple root layouts, remove the top-level layout.js file, and add a layout.js file inside each
route group. This is useful for partitioning an application into
sections that have a completely different UI or experience. The 
and  tags need to be added to each root layout.

My suggestion is that you transform the /(root)/layout into a nested layout by removing the tags html and body.

but I don't have multiple root layouts. one is HomeLayout and one is RootLayout

By using html and or body tag you are defining another root layout. The component name does not affect it. See.
